# Determine the probability p that at least three models match the profile. ( Poisson scheme )

Tags: probability

Suppose that four new computer models M1, M2, M3, M4 are being tested for
their reliability. The probability that a model satisfy the latest market standards are
p1 = 0.8 for model M1, p1 = 0.7 for model M2, p3 = 0.9 for model M3 and p4 = 0.6 for
model M4. Determine the probability p that at least three models match the profile.

I know I have to use the poisson's urn scheme and apply the formula for 
$P(x \geq 3)$ but I am at a loss on how to find the expected value in order to apply the formula so a little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 ways this can happen. They all match the profile, or only one misses, either M1, M2, M3, or M4, and the other three match. So you sum up these 5 probabilities.

The probabilities of these 5 chances are $p_1p_2p_3p_4$, $(1-p_1)p_2p_3p_4$, $p_1(1-p_2)p_3p_4$, $p_1p_2(1-p_3)p_4$, and $p_1p_2p_3(1-p_4)$, respectively. Summing these up with the given $p$ values gives $0.3024+0.0756+0.1296+0.0336+0.2016=0.7428$